# php dom xpath extract all links from all folders in site

Tags: php, dom, curl

I have searched around on stackoverflow and the web and must be missing something here. I have not found exactly what I am looking for. Maybe its called something else.. I have this code below which will grab everything fine in the first folder but will not grab other items from other folders.. example it grabs everything in front of the first / but if you have a site mysite.com/folder2/ it will not grab folder2. Everything is linked. It also does travel backwards too. If you put in the longest link of the site will go all the way to the front of the site. I am not sure what I am missing any pointers would be great.  The site is a joomla site that I am trying to scrap.

```
<?php function storelink($web,$taken) {
$query = "INSERT INTO scanned (web, taken) VALUES ('$web', '$taken')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
  }

   $target_web = "mysite.com";
  $userAgent = 'bobsbot(http://www.somebot.com/bot.html)';

 // make the cURL request to $target_web
 $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_web);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);



  $html= curl_exec($ch);
  if (!$html) {
echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
exit;
}

    // parse the html into a DOMDocument
  $dom = new DOMDocument();
   @$dom->loadHTML($html);

  // grab all the on the page
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/html/body//a");

  for ($i = 0; $i < $hrefs->length; $i++) {
$href = $hrefs->item($i);
$web = $href->getAttribute('href');
storeLink($web,$target_web);
echo "<br />Link saved: $web";




 } ?>
```

Comment: So they site you're trying to get all the links from... Does your code fail to retrieve ALL links or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It only gets all the links in the first folder anything after the first / but noting else.. For example it will get mysite.com/page.html mysite.com/page2.html but it will not continue on to mysite.com/folder2/colors.html or above.. It will on scan up to the first slash.. Not all the way.

Comment: Please expand on "only the first folder"...

Comment: What do you mean by please expand on the first folder?

Comment: Its using a simple joomla script.. I am not sure if it has to do with the .htaccess or not.. At least I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to spider a site and save all URLs. This means you need to recurse when you encounter an URL.

The function you use to start the spider is called `saveLink($web, $taken)`. The function you call when encountering a link is `storeLink($web, $target_web)`. Shouldn't that be `saveLink($web, $target_web)`?

`saveLink()` should be recursive and also execute the cURL request. The cURL URL should be set to the link encountered. This way, it will parse the DOM of all links encountered and follow all links in them.

Comment: Hello, that is correct on that. I did fix that.. however.. it still doesn't scan the whole site..

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your code correctly at first: the function `saveLink` should be recursive and also execute the cURL request. The cURL URL should be set to the link encountered.

This way, it will parse the DOM of all links encountered and follow all links in them.

Comment: No problem. I really appreicate your help so far.. Wouldn't this make it recursive though? curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); Am I missing something?

Comment: No, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION only makes curl follow `Location:` headers in the HTTP headers. This has nothing to do with links in the body of the HTML document. So you have to do the recursion yourself.

Comment: Ok Thank you.. I am going to have to read a few things and I will get back to you thanks

Comment: I have to say though: why build this yourself? There are many fine libaries out there. [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte) for example.

Comment: Biggest reason is I don't want to cross any boundaries with redistribution. Plus someone is willing to pay for it.. So I would love to get a better understanding really. :)

Comment: There would be no issues with redistribution. The license on this component is the MIT license, which is VERY permissive

Comment: I'm not having to much luck with this.. I tried building it in as  if ($url === $target_url) { 
     return ;
  }
  else {
     return $url * storeLink($url,$gathered_from); 
  }

Comment: I didn't mean to the multiple sign in there that was mistake

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24828/discussion-between-user1474885-and-matthijs-van-den-bos)